The relation between KL-divergence and Hellinger distance or Chi-square distance
From "Gibbs, On Choosing and Bounding Probability Metrics", we know that, in general,
$$TV^2(p,q)\leq H^2(p,q)\leq KLD(p,q)\leq d_{\chi^2}(p,q)$$ where $TV(,),H^2(,),KLD(,),\ \text{and}\ d_{\chi^2}(,)$ means the Total variation, Hellinger distance, KL-divergence (relative entropy), and $\chi^2$-distance, relatively, and p, q are two distributions.
Now, assume we just consider all p,q satisfying $KLD(p,q)\leq 1$. The question is if we can find a constant $c>1$ which is not related to $p,q$ such that
$$KLD(p,q)\leq c H^2(p,q)$$ or $$KLD(p,q)\leq c H(p,q)$$
Can someone provide me a hint about these? Thank you!
